# Using Authorization for my application that's straightforward and easy to implement

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authorization

I am new to using OAuth and some of the new Authentication techniques out there, and to be brutally honest I haven't come across an authorization technique that has not made me frustrated and want to pull my hair out trying to implement it in one of my applications.

I've tried to learn the OAuth flows but most of the resources that I came across further confused and frustrated me. I've tried using Authorization Servers like Auth0, and on the surface I thought it was pretty cool until I tried to dive in and implement it in my application. That also frustrated me because their documentation seems to be all over the place and then it still did not work correctly with my application (My application uses ASP.NET Web API, and AngularJS for the front-end).

What I want to do is very simple but I just cant find the right solution. All I want to do is store users and user info in my database or authorization server db, send usernames and passwords to the authorization server and receive an access token that my Web API recognizes, and also handle user roles. I have been trying to create secure login and registration functionality for about a week now, and it's taking time away from more important tasks.

Are there any Authorization servers that I can use that do just what I need it to do without all of the extra mess that I care nothing about at this moment?

Comment: You may benefit from reading [oauth simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/).

Comment: @TheGreatContini Thanks I will definately check that out!

Comment: If you will implement OAuth2 for Authentication, I recommend you to focus on the Implicit Grant flow. Basically, your Client app (AngularJS) tries to access a protected resource, receives a 401 response, then your Client app notices it and redirects your user to the OAuth2 server. The server completes the flow and return to your Angular app. Can be confusing at first, go little by little. Any OAuth2 server works more or less the same